# generate sql script from tables

Tags: squirrel-sql

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/64fac9c8c4.gif](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/64fac9c8c4.gif)

is it possible to generate sql scripts from for all tables ? i want to generate the sql script and import into another database server

Comment: What type of database server is it? If it's mysql, look into mysqldump, a command line utility. Most popular database servers have a similar type of program. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the Squirrel SQL Client program...

Mysqldump: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: i use squirrel-sql to connect to oracle10g

Comment: @Ben - doesn't really answer the question, but it was what I needed anyway so thanks. :-)

Answer (score 23):

Select the tables you want to export, right click, scripts>create table script. It works in  mysql, not sure about oracle.

Comment: If you're wondering where the script goes, it puts it into the SQL window. For me, it was getting some errors and dying, so I used mysqldump as suggested above.

Comment: Would be great if there was a way of doing this for all tables in one go.

Comment: And Scripts -> Create Data Script for table contents. Don't know if this works with bigger data sets.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone on the 3.4.0 version on OSX, I had to do it this way:

```
Select the DB
Session >> SQL Server >> Generate T-SQL Script
Select the Objects/Tables wanted
```

Saves to a file, but gives you no progress indicator, so give it a while to run.