# Get MySQL database DDL using jdbc connection

Tags: mysql

I would like to get DDL statements for an existing MySQL database using a jdbc connection, and not tools like MySQL workbench. Similar to the export_objects statement in HP Vertica.

https://www.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/CopyExportData/ExportingObjects.htm

Is this possible?

Comment: A sql conection doesn't seem very useful if you are not connecting  from something to a DBMS.

Comment: I'm using SQL Squirrel as my client. It uses a jdbc connection under the hood to connect to MySQL. I'd like to get a text results that contains the full DDL of the database.

Comment: Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062010/generate-sql-script-from-tables and the squirrel documantation?

Comment: That works tables, but not for stored procedures. And I would still like to do it for any jdbc connection - perhaps java.